# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljvm:during compiling jni project

Tags: java, c, linux, java-native-interface, fuse

i'm compiling a jni project.here is detail of the problem i encountering:
r

```
oot@kaiwiiho:/home/kaiwii/svn# make
gcc -shared build/utimebufClass.o build/contextClass.o build/fsClass.o build/javafuse_jni.o build/statClass.o build/statvfsClass.o build/fileinfoClass.o build/conninfoClass.o -o build/libjavafuse.so
gcc -g -Wall `pkg-config --cflags fuse` -Iinclude -I/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/include -I/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/include/linux `pkg-config --libs fuse`  -L/usr/java/packages/lib/i386 -L/lib -L/usr/lib -ljvm -Lbuild -ljavafuse src/javafuse.c -o javafuse
src/javafuse.c: In function ‘javafuse_readdir’:
src/javafuse.c:2194:22: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
src/javafuse.c:2195:25: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
src/javafuse.c:2207:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
src/javafuse.c:2208:18: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
src/javafuse.c:2256:16: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
src/javafuse.c:2257:19: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
src/javafuse.c:2271:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
src/javafuse.c:2272:18: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
src/javafuse.c: In function ‘javafuse_releasedir’:
src/javafuse.c:2332:12: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
src/javafuse.c: In function ‘javafuse_fsyncdir’:
src/javafuse.c:2420:12: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljvm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [javafuse] 错误 1
root@kaiwiiho:/home/kaiwii/svn# ldconfig
root@kaiwiiho:/home/kaiwii/svn# gedit /etc/ld.so.conf
root@kaiwiiho:/home/kaiwii/svn# make
gcc -shared build/utimebufClass.o build/contextClass.o build/fsClass.o build/javafuse_jni.o build/statClass.o build/statvfsClass.o build/fileinfoClass.o build/conninfoClass.o -o build/libjavafuse.so
gcc -g -Wall `pkg-config --cflags fuse` -Iinclude -I/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/include -I/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/include/linux `pkg-config --libs fuse`  -L/usr/java/packages/lib/i386 -L/lib -L/usr/lib -ljvm -Lbuild -ljavafuse src/javafuse.c -o javafuse
src/javafuse.c: In function ‘javafuse_readdir’:
src/javafuse.c:2194:22: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
src/javafuse.c:2195:25: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
src/javafuse.c:2207:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
src/javafuse.c:2208:18: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
src/javafuse.c:2256:16: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
src/javafuse.c:2257:19: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
src/javafuse.c:2271:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
src/javafuse.c:2272:18: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
src/javafuse.c: In function ‘javafuse_releasedir’:
src/javafuse.c:2332:12: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
src/javafuse.c: In function ‘javafuse_fsyncdir’:
src/javafuse.c:2420:12: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljvm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [javafuse] 错误 1
```

And for sake that the the libjvm.so have aready exisited in the /usr/lib,i directly make a conf file,/etc/ld.so.conf.d/my.conf:

```
/usr/lib
/usr/local/lib
```

and then i use command ldconfig.
but unfortunately,i still encounter the same problem yet.
Any idea?thx

Answer (score 2):

This command:

```
gcc -g -Wall `pkg-config --cflags fuse` -Iinclude \
  -I/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/include \
  -I/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/include/linux `pkg-config --libs fuse`  \
  -L/usr/java/packages/lib/i386 -L/lib -L/usr/lib -ljvm -Lbuild -ljavafuse \
  src/javafuse.c -o javafuse
```

is incorrect. The order of libraries and sources on the link line [matters](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html), and your order is wrong.

But that's not what your problem is right now. You insist that `libjvm.so` exists in `/usr/lib`, but have shown no evidence that it does. What does `ls -l /usr/lib/libjvm.so` actually print?

Note that it would be highly unusual to find `libjvm.so` in `/usr/lib`. Usually one would expect to find it in e.g. `/usr/java/packages/lib/i386/server`, and you are not searching  *that* directory.

Update:

> well. `libjvm.so` is not actually in the `/usr/lib` but in `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/i386/server`

In that case, you need to add `-L/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/i386/server` to your link line.

> And i gedit a conf file ...

Obviously that's not sufficient.

Comment: well.libjvm.so is not actually in the /usr/lib but in /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/i386/server.And i gedit a conf file in the /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/i386/server containing,/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/i386/server.use command,ldconfig and reboot.but it still prompt the same error.

Comment: thanks...it works...actually I used straight forwardly this -  " gcc -g -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/include -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/include/linux -L /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/i386/server -ljvm CallJVM.c " and a.out was created. Then I need to link it with libjvm.so present in server folder as mentioned in post.

Comment: I found a similar problem when installing python javabridge module:  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -ljvm. I worked it around creating a symbolic link: cd /usr/lib; ln -s /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1_6_0-ibm-1.6.0/jre/lib/amd64/default/libjvm.so libjvm.so

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming because JAVA_HOME & LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not consistent for Linux.So after analysis i discover that JAVA_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is resetting everytime whenever the terminal window is closed.
So setting the JAVA_HOME permanently resolved the error like:-
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib64: