# Error base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'JNIEnv {aka _JNIEnv}' when create NDK project

Tags: android, android-ndk, native-code

I create my first NDK project, that show some text on screen.
I use native method in class NativeLib in java and implement in a class in C.
But I received an error base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'JNIEnv {aka _JNIEnv}

```
 #include <jni.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <android/log.h>

#define DEBUG_TAG "MY_NDK_DEMO"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_helloworld_NativeLib_helloWorld
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj) {
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF("Hello World JNI!");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘JNIEnv’](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764948/error-base-operand-of-has-non-pointer-type-jnienv)

Answer (score 6):

try `return env->NewStringUTF("Hello World JNI!");`

Comment: Why is that different for C++?

Answer (score 1):

c++ is different from c
so to make it work
use 
env->NewStringUTF("Hy");